# Dunce Cap triangle homotopy equivalent to $S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-verification, fundamental-groups

> Why is Dunce Cap triangle homotopy equivalent to $S^1$.

Yes, maybe it is not the correct expression, but i mean that the dunce cap can be represented as a quotient space of a triangle by identifying the 3 sides as pictured below (1. picture from left).

and if you consider only the edges, this should be homotopy equivalent to $S^1$, and i ask, if my ''transformation'' in the picture is correct.

[image: Dunce Cap]

Comment: Is this subspace of the dunce cap not in fact homeomorphic to the circle? As far as I can tell, your image represents my intuition as well.

Comment: i see this dunce cap for the first time, it was a part of my fundamental group exercise, so i don't know if they're even homeomorph.

Answer (score 16):

The term Dunce Cap is usually applied to the adjunction space $S^1 \cup_f D^2$ where the disc $D^2$ is attached to the circle $S^1$ by a map which we can write $a +a -a$ But $$a +a -a\simeq a+(a-a)\simeq a+0 \simeq a,$$ so $f$ is homotopic to the identity map $i: S^1 \to S^1$. So the Dunce Cap as defined here is homotopy equivalent to $S^1 \cup_i D^2$, which is clearly homeomorphic to $D^2$, and so is contractible. See p. 295 of [Topology and Groupoids](https://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html). I think this is what you mean by your argument, which has caught the essential idea.

You might like a picture (from the above book) of the identifications up to the last stage:

[image: Dunce]

The next stage is to identify the two arrowed circles. I have made this in plasticine.

Comment: I'm surprised that it is actually constructable in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Answer (score 2):

Your proof looks good and would be accepted by anyone reasonable marking it. (Perhaps throw in some words as well so that the reader is clear about what the image means.)

As far as a *rigorous* proof goes. I would start by showing that the space, let us call it $D$, is compact (it's the continuous image of a compact space so is compact) and that $D$ is a topological manifold. This can be seen by noting that each of the vertices are mapped to the same point in the quotient and a small neighbourhood of this point is homeomorphic to an open interval. The image of the points on the interior of the edges also clearly have a small neighbourhood homeomorphic to an open interval. It follows that $D$ is a compact connected topological $1$-dimensional manifold without boundary and so can only be a circle up to homeomorphism.

This proof is obviously overkill (and uses a fairly strong theorem - $1$-manifolds are disjoint unions of circles and real lines) and a picture really is the best way to go here. I am still slightly concerned why you mention the weaker result that $D$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$. Is it possible you really want to show that the 'punctured dunce cap' is homotopy equivalent to the circle?

Comment: Yes, your idea might be correct, but as i said, it was only a part of an exercise, the real exercise is to find the fundamental group of the dunce cap. So to meet the conditions of Van-Kampen theorem, i had to define two open sets. as the first i choosed a circle in the interior of the triangle and as the second the edges of the triangle, and i've been told that this should be homotopy equivalent to $S^1$

Comment: That would be the standard way, although remember that the sets need to be open, cover the space, be path-connected and the intersection needs to be non-empty and path-connected. The space you have mentioned is not open (but a small 'tubular neighbourhood' would be).

Comment: This is true, but the assistants have said that this is the way we have to do it, but they didn't say why ?, Now why can we neglect that epsilon thickness of triangle and consider it as a ''wire'' ?

Comment: Because the 'epsilon thickness' can be deformation retracted onto the subspace $D$ and so they are homotopy equivalent.

Comment: Maybe you could have defined $D$, I was very confused...

Comment: @krey Sorry, I thought it was clear that 'the space' when I first mentioned $D$ was the one in the OP's question. That is, the $1$-skeleton of the Dunce cap space.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just looking at the dunce's cap topology for the first time.
Reading the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunce_hat_(topology)) it states:

> The dunce hat is contractible, but not collapsible. Contractibility can be easily seen by noting that the dunce hat embeds
>   in the 3-ball and the 3-ball deformation retracts onto the dunce hat.
>   Alternatively, note that the dunce hat is the CW-complex obtained by
>   gluing the boundary of a 2-cell onto the circle.

So if it is the case that it's contractible then I think that makes it homotopy equivalent to a point, again from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space):

> A contractible space is precisely one with the homotopy type of a point. It follows that all the homotopy groups of a contractible space
>   are trivial.

I know I'm not offering any new proofs myself but thought this was an interesting answer.