# Dunce hat contractible

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I try to prove that the Dunce hat is contractible.
I thought about taking the straight line homotopy between the triangle and a point (using that triangle is a convex set), and then composite between the projection and the homotopy, but I am not sure in that.
I will glad for little help:)

Comment: Does Ronnie Brown's answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624416/dunce-cap-triangle-homotopy-equivalent-to-s1/3489321#3489321 help?

Comment: unfortunately no:( I try to prove this theorem by finding the homotopy itself between the identity map a constant map of the dunce hat..but so far I cannot find it

Comment: What the answer I cited suggests is doing it in two stages: in the first stage you contract two edges of the triangle to a single point. what you then have is a disc. and that contracts to point.